# Suds: Type not found on response

Tags: python, types, wsdl, response, suds

I'm having a hard time getting a python SOAP client based on suds to parse a response: the client is constructed correctly and parses the WSDL just fine. As far as I can see there are no imports in the WSDL, so this doesn't seem like a typical `ImportDoctor` issue.

Relevant bits from the WSDL:

```
        <xsd:complexType name="getFontsRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:int" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="TAWSAccessKey" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="getFontsResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Fonts" type="tns:FontType[]"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="FontType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

My Code:

```
    self.soap_client = Client(settings.WSDL_URL)
    self.factory = self.soap_client.factory
    self.service = self.soap_client.service
    # ...
    getFontsRequest = self.factory.create('getFontsRequest')
    getFontsRequest.UserID = settings.WS_UID
    getFontsRequest.TAWSAccessKey = settings.WS_KEY

    self.service.getFonts(getFontsRequest)
```

The last line throws this exception:

```
...
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 63, in resolve
raise TypeNotFound(qref)
TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(FontType[], http://www.type-applications.com/character_set/, )'
```

My understanding is that the webservice returns an array of `FontType` objects (i.e. `FontType[]`), as specified in the `getFontResponse` method, but fails to define the `FontType[]` type, and merely describes `FontType`.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only think I can advise is to add debug logging and to search somewhere inside it. By the way you can paste suds client and transport logging output here - this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by contacting the WSDL provider and asking him to fix the (broken) WSDL. Unfortunately I'm unaware of any code-based solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a job for the [`ImportDoctor`](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs).  It's surprisingly common to run across broken WSDLs.

Try this:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor

wsdl_url = settings.WSDL_URL

# Fix missing types with ImportDoctor
schema_url = 'http://www.type-applications.com/character_set/'
schema_import = Import(schema_url)
schema_doctor = ImportDoctor(schema_import)

# Pass doctor to Client
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, doctor=schema_doctor)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should actually have specified that in the question, but this is pretty much exactly the first thing I tried, but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, but all the examples I've seen of ImportDoctor, refer to the _instantiation_ of the Client, i.e. when the schema is first loaded. From what I've seen suds fails early in case of a broken schema.  In my case the schema is loaded just fine, and the Type error happens at call-time.

Comment: Can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586989/not-able-to-create-a-soap-filter-in-suds be fixed on similar lines?