# WSDL Type not found

Tags: django, wsdl, suds

I am trying to get a WSDL response using suds for django. But I get a type not found error for no reason.

```
Type not found: 'ProfileInfo'
```

This is how my xml should look like:

```
 <Profiles>
   <ProfileInfo>
     <Profile ProfileType="1">
       <Customer>
       </Customer>
     </Profile>
   </ProfileInfo>
 </Profiles>
```

The suds client supplies me with 2 objects:

```
ns0:ProfileType
ns0:ProfilesType
```

There is no ProfileInfo object.

This is what I do:
I create a ProfilesType object:

```
profiles = client.factory.create('ns0:ProfilesType')
```

This object looks like this:

```
(ProfilesType){
   ProfileInfo[] = <empty>
}
```

As there is no ProfileInfo object which I can create, I try two approaches:
1. Append ProfileType object to ProfileInfo

```
profile = client.factory.create('ns0:ProfileType')
profiles.ProfileInfo.append(profile)
```

This generates the following XML which is rejected by the server.

```
 <Profiles>
   <ProfileInfo>
     <Customer>
     </Customer>
   </ProfileInfo>
 </Profiles>
```

2.. Create a dummy profileinfo object and add profiletype to it:

```
 profile_info = {"ProfileInfo": []}
 profile_info["ProfileInfo"].append(profile)
 profiles.ProfileInfo.append(profile_info)
```

This throws the error "Type not found: 'ProfileInfo'"

What do I do? I've been trying various combinations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: found this yet? I get the same issue. So in case you solved it, please share the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a dummy ProfileInfo object.

```
profile_info = {"Profile": []}
profile_info["Profile"].append(profile)
profiles = client.factory.create('ns0:ProfilesType')
profiles.ProfileInfo.append(profile_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Am going to try the suds doctor, might be helpful, see: [Suds: Type not found on response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654805/suds-type-not-found-on-response)

This answer got me on the right track. The import doctor did not work, but this did:

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs

I opened the schema, to see where the missing type refered to, and there found a namespace and location,a nd filled this in here:

```
from suds.xsd.sxbasic import Import

ns = '<fill in the namespace for the missing type>'
schema_url  = '<fill in the url>'
Import.bind(ns, location)
# repeat this for all missing types
# and than create the client
client = Client(wsdl_url)
message= '%s' % client
# log the message, and this works for me!
```